# C difference between compilation of static local variable and static global variable

Tags: c, code-generation

I know what the difference between these types of variables is, but I'm wondering if making a static variable local actually affects, or can affect the compiler's code-generation in any way.

Comment: A static variable declared globally is available only within that translation unit but one declared within a block,say inside a function, will act as block variable.

Comment: There's no reason for it to affect the compiler's code-generation in any way. Aside from differences in their scope, they behave the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static variables declared at file scope have the same properties as static variables declared locally (aside from their *scope*, i.e. visibility region of the identifier). Both kinds have the same storage duration. Both kinds are initialized before program's startup.

There's no reason to expect them to behave differently in terms of code generation.

As a side note: static variables cannot be declared locally in *inline definitions* of functions, but it is not related to code generation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, static external variables (i.e., static variables outside of the scope of any function) are restricted in scope to their *translation unit*. This is different from a `.c` file.  Basically, a translation unit is the `.c` file after all preprocessing has completed and every `#include` file has been added.

A static local variable is different from a static external variable in that it can only be referenced from within the function in which it was declared.  It is also notably different from a normal local variable in that it retains its value across function calls (ask me for a snippet to demonstrate, if you're interested).

Does this clarify the difference in your mind?